# Centering a two side by side div's

Tags: css

I am a little rusty with css and I am stuck on this, what I am trying to achieve is to have two div's side by side with an image overlapping the two top corners, This I have done much (I hope correctly), what I am stuck doing is trying to centre the two side-by-side  divs which i currently cant do without breaking it

any help would be great, Thanks

```
    <style>
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* add this to contain floated children */
}
#first {
    width: 300px;
    float:left; /* add this */
    color:#FFF;
    padding:0 5px 5px 5px;
    background: url(view.image?id=598) 0 100% #fcb033 no-repeat;
}
#second {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding:0 5px 5px 5px;
    color:#FFF;
    background: url(view.image?id=595) 100% 100% #c1d72e  no-repeat;

}
    #overlayleft{
        position:absolute;
        top:-40px; 
        left:-30px;
    }

    #overlayright{
        position:absolute;
        top:-40px; 
        left:570px;
    }
    </style>


    <div id"wrapper">
    <div id="first"><div id="overlayleft"><img alt="Dr Sayer" height="94" src="view.image?Id=592" width="93" /></div><h1 style="text-align:right">Dr John Sayer</h1><p>Cystic kidney diseases, such as polycystic kidney
    disease (PKD), are responsible for ten per cent of
    patients requiring dialysis and transplantation in
    the UK. As with most cystic kidney diseases, PKD
    is a genetic condition which causes fluid-filled
    sacks to develop on the interior and exterior of
    the kidneys. These sacks gradually replace normal
    kidney tissue, enlarging the organs and reducing
    their ability to function – eventually causing them
    to fail altogether. A recently discovered gene,
    involved in the onset of cystic kidney diseases,
    has provided a basis for the work of Dr John Sayer.
    Dr Sayer is studying this specific gene closely and
    hopes not only to improve our understanding of
    the molecules which cause cystic kidney diseases,
    but also test potential new drug treatments aimed
    at preventing the formation of cysts.</p></div>

    <div id="second"><div id="overlayright"><img alt="Donate" height="94" src="view.image?Id=592" width="93" /></div><h1>Carol Norbury</h1>
    <p>Carol Norbury’s family has a prolonged history of polycystic
    kidney disease. Her husband, John, was diagnosed with the condition in 1996, before
    going on to suffer complete renal
    failure in late 2004. Luckily, Carol
    was found to be a suitable organ
    donor. However, since then, each
    of Carol and John’s three children
    has been diagnosed with
    the condition.</p></div>
    <div class"clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a width on the wrapper for the "margin:0 auto;" to work.

AND you're missing the **equal sign** on the **wrapper id**